# Efficiency with Thread.sleep()

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-sleep, coding-efficiency

I have a bit of code here that works like how I want it to.  All it is is a countdown in seconds to a particular date I determine in the code. I'm using `Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);` to update a JLabel with the current time left until the date. The problem is that the JLabel doesn't refresh every second like it is supposed to. Sometimes it updates every 2 seconds, other times it takes a full 10 seconds to update. I believe it has something to do with how I'm calling my methods, but I'm not quite sure how to make it more efficient.

Here is the main method that calls the method to update the JLabel within the Thread:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    initUI();
    try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            getTime();
        }
    } catch(Exception e){System.out.println("An error has occured...");}
}
```

Here is the method called by the method called by the main method. This method eventually sends the seconds remaining variable to a 3rd method:

```
public static void getTime()
{
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Gets abstract current time in ms
    long now = c.getTimeInMillis();

    c.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    // Gets current time in ms
    long msPassed = now - c.getTimeInMillis();
    // There are 86,400,000 milliseconds in a day
    // Gets the seconds remaining in the day
    long secRemaining = (86400000 - msPassed) / 1000;

    //-----------------------------------------------------// 
    // Creates a new calendar for today
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    int currentDayOfYear = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    // Creates a calendar for November 20th, 2016
    Calendar aniv = new GregorianCalendar(2016,10,20);
    aniv.set(Calendar.MONTH, 10);
    aniv.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
    int aniversary = aniv.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);

    remaining = ((aniversary - currentDayOfYear) * 24 * 60 * 60) + secRemaining;
    setTextOnScreen(remaining);
}
```

And finally, this is the method that rewrites the JLabel (called by the method above):

```
public static void setTextOnScreen(long num)
{
    text.setForeground(Color.GREEN);
    text.setLocation((int)width/2 - 150, 50);
    text.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.BOLD, 48));
    text.setSize(300,150);

    text.setText("" + num);
    panel.add(text);
}
```

I'm not including the rest of the code because it should be irrelevant, but if you want to see that as well, just let me know.

Comment: Your sleep is for 2 seconds

Answer (score 3):

Two problems:

1. You're calling `text.setSomething()` and `panel.add` from a background thread, which is not the UI thread that you should be using. Try using `SwingUtils.invokeLater()` or `SwingUtils.invokeAndWait()` and call code that touches the UI there.
2. After calling your `set` methods, you should also call `text.invalidate()` to signal that the UI components needs to be updated... otherwise the UI thread won't notice that the component needs to be remeasured and redrawn.

Answer (score 1):

You should only be updating GUI components in the Event Loop. If you attempt to update them in other threads you can get unpredictable results. I suggest using a swing Timer for periodic tasks to be run in the GUI Event Loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `Timer`

It has a method `#scheduleAtFixedRate` which will accept a task to perform, a time to start performing it, and an interval that it should run the task from.

Wrap your scheduled actions into a class that extends `TimerTask` to use with this method.

Here are the javadocs for this class in Java 7 https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html